# Polluting domain types by implementing infrastructure-related interfaces

Tags: c#, .net, dns, aop

Did about 30 minutes worth of searching, found lots of relevant info, but none that addresses this particular concern, hope I'm not repeating a common question.

I would like to know what the general consensus is in regard to implementing infrastructure-related interfaces in domain types. Everything I've read about DDD leads me to believe that this is to be avoided, as this understandably detracts from the conciseness of the model.

I am, however, at a point where I'm uncertain as to how to work around this. Specifically, I've got a domain type that would be perfectly fine to use in my presentation layer, except that I'd like to display an instance of it in a control that requires it implements IComparable. I would rather not 'pollute' my type with an implementation of this interface.

I think (perhaps naively) my options are:

1. Use a Data Transfer Object (DTO), have it implement the interface, and use an instance  of that in my
   presentation layer.
2. I'm vaguely
   familiar with the fundamentals of
   AOP - perhaps there's a suitable
   technique in this realm?
3. Perhaps
   related to option 2 - code 'weaving'?
   I know very little of why/when to
   consider this, but am I bumping up
   against it now?
4. Bite the bullet,
   and implement the bit of code
   that it takes to satisfy the contract.
5. Some voodoo-magic I've
   never even heard of?

If anybody cares to recommend 2, 3, or 5 - could you point me in the direction of some reading material that might help get me started?

Thx in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, after some deliberation on all my options (including the additional ones provided), I think I'm happiest with a ViewModel variant of my Model class. I'm thinking that it's wise to have a type who's sole responsibility is to 'visually represent' a Model type. As mentioned, its visual responsibilities could (and likely will) expand beyond my current requirement of implementing an interface.

Comment: this is the MVC variant that WPF uses; I have also used this model in regular WinForms applications to ensure that model changes are marshalled across to the main GUI thread before affecting the view (though there are other solutions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

implement an intermediate "View-Model" class:

- the View part knows how to talk to the user-interface (databinding, IComparable, et al)
- it holds a reference to the Model (domain) object
- it exposes the properties of the Model object (and relays change notifications if necessary)

Answer (score 1):

1. This will work, and should be fine.

2-4. These are really the same option.  The difference is in **how** you implement the code to satisfy the contract.  Code weaving and AOP are still "polluting" your object, but they're doing the work for you in a semi-automatic way (ie: you just put an attribute on your object, and it implements it post-compile).  The final result is the same, though, whether you implement the object or use AOP/code gen.

5. My suggestion below:

Most of the time, anything that requires `IComparable<T>` also provides an option to pass an `IComparer<T>`.  If your control does, this would let you implement the comparing logic external to your data objects, and just pass it in as well.  I would investigate this as an option first.

Otherwise, my suggestion would be to just implement `IComparable<T>` directly in the object.  If you don't want to "pollute" the API, just implement it explicitly.